# MemoryMappedFile CreateViewStream throws an exception "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MmapedFile", MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite);
var acc = mmf.CreateViewStream();
```

The above code throws an exception

> The parameter is incorrect

.
The exception isn't the documented `UnauthorizedAccessException`, but a general Exception object.
I have tried with `CreateViewAccesor`, with different rights (Read, Write, Execute), all the same result.

**Update**
A more detailed explanation.
I have the following code:

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MmapedFile", MemoryMappedFileRights.Read, HandleInheritability.None);
```

I check some information inside the MemoryMappedFile, and based on the information i decide whether to update it. Once I decide to update it, I run the code at the beginning of the post.

Furthermore, I have a different process which also accesses the MemoryMappedFile, but only for reading (to keep it alive).
Could it be that the other process holding the mmf in read state is causing this error? If so, why isn't the exception the unauthorized exception? And how can i update a mmf which is in use?

Comment: Does the specified memory-mapped file exists? Are you 100% sure for that? Are you sure that your process has access to the memory mapped file?

Comment: Yes, i haven't posted the full source. I will update the question with a longer source code and more information.

Comment: Is this: HandleInheritability.None the cause?

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error, means "one of your arguments is nonsense".  The obvious candidate is MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite, that will fail if the code that *created* the MMF did not permit write access.  Code we cannot see.